# Xubuntu 16.04 boots so fast, network not up on-time. Can the test be delayed?

Tags: boot, xubuntu, nic

I upgraded my Xubuntu 16.04; removed the SSD disk, installed SSD M2 memory card.
Xubuntu now boots in 15sec instead of 40.
Unfortunately, the system now boots so fast, the NIC is slower than the boot process. 
I always get a popup saying The Network is Offline and I must wait till I can use the mouse to click the Ok button. By then the network is up, both wired and wifi.
If I return to the previous hardware setup, the network is detected on-time for the test.
So my question: Can the test of the network being up be delayed?

PS. I just noticed that the shutdown process is also too fast. It 'hangs' on: `A stop job is running for Session c1 of user ... (1min 30s)`.
I changed `/etc/systemd/system.conf`, applied `DefaultTimeoutStopSec=10s` to let the watchdog kick in and let shutdown proceed.
My question on this: Is this in anyway harmful ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the questions can be closed.
I just was notified that a few packages required upgrading. After the usual `apt upgrade` and a reboot, both my questions are no longer relevant.
The boot time has even improved to a whopping 11.210 seconds and the shutdown process is down to some 5 seconds.
As I was not able to pinpoint the initial cause of my issue, I cannot tell you which upgraded package(s) resolved it.